# How to center the images and text in each row of the QlistWidget？

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, pyside, pyside6

```py
class ImageListWidget(QListWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ImageListWidget, self).__init__()
        self.setIconSize(QSize(120,200))
        self.ids = []
        self.setViewMode(QListView.IconMode)
        self.setFlow(QListView.LeftToRight)
        self.setResizeMode(QListView.Adjust)
        self.setMovement(QListView.Static)
        self.setItemAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

    def add_image_items(self,image, id):

        #image = self.resize_icon(image)
        item = QListWidgetItem()
        print(image.size())
        item.setIcon(QIcon(image))
        item.setText(str(id))
        item.setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.ids.append(id)
        self.addItem(item)
```

I want to center the images and text in each line of the QlistWidget,
but the QlistWidgetItem doesn't have an API for centering the icon,
so hope you can help me ?

[image]

Comment: Use the ```QListView``` and ```QStyledItemDelegate```.